# Tags order when getting XML from XML element (XML contains XML)?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have XML which contains XML and i want parse it using JAXB

```
<DATA>qwqweqwe<aa>zxc</aa></DATA><TEMPM>asdasd<aa /> eee</TEMPM>
```

parser

```
public static NotificationRequest parse(String xml)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, JAXBException {
    xml = makeXMLValid(xml);
    NotificationRequest ret = new NotificationRequest();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
            .newInstance(NotificationRequest.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    ret = (NotificationRequest) jaxbUnmarshaller
            .unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));

    return ret;
}
```

NotificationRequest

```
@XmlAnyElement(value = XMLParserDataHandler.class)
public String DATA;
@XmlAnyElement(value = XMLParserTempmHandler.class)
public String TEMPM;
```

XMLPArserDataHandler

```
private static final String PARAMETERS_START_TAG = "<DATA>";
private static final String PARAMETERS_END_TAG = "</DATA>";
private StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter();

@Override
public StreamResult createUnmarshaller(ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
    return new StreamResult(xmlWriter);
}

@Override
public String getElement(StreamResult rt) {
    String xml = rt.getWriter().toString();
    int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(PARAMETERS_START_TAG)
            + PARAMETERS_START_TAG.length();
    int endIndex = xml.indexOf(PARAMETERS_END_TAG);
    return xml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
}

@Override
public Source marshal(String n, ValidationEventHandler errorHandler) {
    try {
        String xml = PARAMETERS_START_TAG + n.trim() + PARAMETERS_END_TAG;
        StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
        return new StreamSource(xmlReader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

XMLParserTampmHandler (Similar to DATA handler)

```
...
private static final String PARAMETERS_START_TAG = "<TEMPM>";
private static final String PARAMETERS_END_TAG = "</TEMPM>";
....
```

And when I run

```
    NotificationRequest request = XMLParser.parse(xml);

    System.out.println(request.TEMPM);
    System.out.println(request.DATA);
```

On output I see

```
null
qwqweqwe<aa>zxc</aa>
```

When I change order in XML to

```
<TEMPM>asdasd<aa /> eee</TEMPM><DATA>qwqweqwe<aa>zxc</aa></DATA>
```

I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -6
```

In `XMLParserDataHandler.java:29`

When I'm using only one `@XmlAnyElement` annotation everything works fine.

How can I red XML from XML where I have more than one tag that contains XML using JAXB?

---

I created new, simple project. It shows the code http://pastebin.com/apJf0D72

Comment: There is no way the code in XMLParserDataHandler as you have shown it can produce an index -6. indexOf doens't return less than -1, and you are adding non-negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as it is, with the input you've shown doesn't appear to have any issues with it. What you're probably not showing us is the whole input stream or your main method that shows the whole workflow.

Your error is being caused by the `substring` method that is returning based on the values returned by:

```
int beginIndex = xml.indexOf(PARAMETERS_START_TAG)
        + PARAMETERS_START_TAG.length();
int endIndex = xml.indexOf(PARAMETERS_END_TAG);
```

Suppose you had a line that didn't contain those tags, your return values would be:

```
beginIndex: -1 + 6 = 5
endIndex: -1
```

`substring` would then return an error with an invalid index of -6 (end - begin = -1 - 5 = -6)

My suggestion would be to clean up your code and add some error protection and show us anything else we might be missing.

Comment: The code is pretty clean. I created new project http://pastebin.com/apJf0D72 . 5 really simple classes.

Comment: Well, given your input string shown above, and the DataHandler code you have here, I didn't run into any issues, order independent. Something you've got in your full program is causing your issues, which stems from the inability to find those tags in the input xml.